# How do i display a custom background image from my drawables instead of drawing color

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have the following code which I got from a youtube tutorial for drawing canvas:

(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6NBt36fO0iw):

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvasporch) {
    canvasporch.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

    for (int i = temps.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        temps.get(i).onDraw(canvasporch);

    for (Sprite sprite : sprites){          
    sprite.onDraw(canvasporch);
```

This works just fine. The only problem is instead of having the color Black as background, I want to display an image from my drawable folder as the background for my sprites. I've tried using drawBitmap() but I cannot seem to make it work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Create a member variable to store the Bitmap:

```
Bitmap spriteBackground;
```

2) In onCreate() (or some other initialization function) load the bitmap from the drawable:

```
spriteBackground = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sprite_background);
```

3) Draw the bitmap using drawBitmap() inside onDraw():

```
canvasporch.drawBitmap(spriteBackground, 0, 0, null);
```

If you want to scale the bitmap to cover the canvas then either scale it at load time using createScaledBitmap (uses more memory) or apply a matrix transform to the canvas (possibly slower).

Another way is to pass the canvas bounds to drawBitmap(), like this:

```
canvasporch.drawBitmap(spriteBackground, null, canvasporch.getClipBounds(), null);
```

Comment: If it works can you please mark the answer as accepted so other people know it has already been answered. Also muh precious internet points.